# sitecore How to search once we have lucene index

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

After searching and reading a lot from Internet I manage create an Index using Lucene. My index name is: `my_text_index`. I have used Luke and I can see the index is created now with some data inside it (title of the items).

Now I have no idea at all how I can use this index to search using Sitecore API.

It would be very nice of you guys if you can write some steps for a beginner like me about "How to search from index in Sitecore".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lot of tutorials and guides in the Internet about Sitecore search. It's very similar in Sitecore 7 and Sitecore 8 so you can use both of them.

First thing you should check is Sitecore documentation: [Developer's Guide to Item Buckets and Search](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/developer's_guide_to_item_buckets_and%20search_sc7-a4.pdf) (the most interesting part for me starts from chapter 5.3).

In the shortcut, create a class for your items (it can inherit from Sitecore `SearchResultItem` class but it's not required if you want to handle standard Sitecore fields by yourself), e.g.:

```cs
public class Person : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("firstname_t")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [IndexField("surname_t")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

and use code like that to get the results:

```cs
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("my_text_index").CreateSearchContext())
{
     IQueryable<Person> query = context.GetQueryable<Person>().Where(p=> p.Firstname.Equals("John"));
}
```

And that's it. You don't need anything else to start using Sitecore Search API with Sitecore 7.

And here is a really nice ["Sitecore 7 Search - a quickstart guide" article](http://www.bekagool.com/news-and-insights/sitecore-7-search-a-quickstart-guide)

Comment: I would add there is also the predicatebuilder which is worth having a look at (depending on your version of Sitecore).  if you are going to be doing a lot of where(X=>X.somevalue == "") ect :)

Comment: @CharlieAfford totally agree. `PredicateBuilder` is described in the article I linked.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty detailed rundown of the steps to create and index all the way to querying the index for results.

http://mrstevenzhao.blogspot.com/2014/04/sitecore-set-up-new-lucene-index-and.html